# pdftools package in r - error: Invalid Font Weight

Tags: r, pdftotext

I am getting the below error, does any one are having any solutions on Invalid Font Error in R:

```
error: Invalid Font Weight
trying URL 'http://wolterskluwer.com/binaries/content/assets/wk/pdf/investors/annual-reports/wolters-kluwer_2015_sustainability_report.pdf'
Content type 'application/pdf;charset=UTF-8' length 1825508 bytes (1.7 MB)
downloaded 1.7 MB
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This means the PDF has some corrupt attributes, but you can safely ignore these warnings. The functionality still works:

```
txt <- pdftools::pdf_text("http://wolterskluwer.com/binaries/content/assets/wk/pdf/investors/annual-reports/wolters-kluwer_2015_sustainability_report.pdf")
cat(txt)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply..  Additionally just thought of checking if the pdftools package is able to exclude few of files in case they are not opening example - http://www.sedar.com/GetFile.do?lang=EN&docClass=18&issuerNo=00032942&fileName=/csfsprod/data129/filings/01892300/00000001/z%3A%5CSEDAR%5CBMI%5C070341%5C0005%5CCode%5D.pdf