# Loading multiple pdf into R with pdftools causes the error: "PDF error: Invalid Font Weight"

Tags: r, web-scraping, text-mining

I have web scraped multiple pdf files using R, however when I try to load them as txt into my enviroment all at once it causes the error "PDF error: Invalid Font Weight" which does not happen if I try to load a file individually

My attempt has been using the following code:

```
# libraries

library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)

# Define the base URL for the target website
base_url <- "https://www.caixabankresearch.com/es/publicaciones/informe-mensual?search=&from=&to=&page="

# Define the number of pages to download PDF files from
num_pages <- 17

# Loop over each page and download the PDF files
for (page_num in 0:num_pages) {
  # Construct the URL for the current page
    url <- paste0(base_url, page_num)
  
  # Read the HTML content from the current page
  page <- read_html(url)
  
  # Find all links that point to PDF files and extract their URLs
  pdf_links <- page %>% 
    html_nodes("a[href$='.pdf']") %>% 
    html_attr("href") %>% 
    url_absolute(url)
  
  # Download each PDF file to your working directory
  for (pdf_link in pdf_links) {
    download.file(pdf_link, basename(pdf_link), mode = "wb", timeout = 30)
    cat(paste0("Downloaded ", basename(pdf_link), " from page ", page_num, "\n"))
  }
}
```

Then I tried to load all the pdf into R using the following code:

```
# libraries

library(tidyverse)
library(pdftools)

# directory path where the PDF files are stored

directory_caixa <- "C:/TFM/caixa"

# list of PDF files in the directory

pdf_files_caixa <- list.files(directory_caixa, pattern = ".pdf$", full.names = TRUE)

# Split the pdf_files_caixa string into individual file names

pdf_files_caixa <- strsplit(pdf_files_caixa, "\\s+")
```

Alternative 1:

```
# Create an empty list to store the extracted text from each PDF file
text_caixa <- list()

# Loop through the PDF files and extract the text from each file

for (i in seq_along(pdf_files_caixa)) {
  # Extract the text from the current PDF file
  text <- pdftools::pdf_text(pdf_files_caixa[[i]])
  
  # Add the extracted text to the pdf_text list
  text_caixa[[i]] <- text
}
```

Alternative 2:

```
# make a data frame with text

text_caixa <- data.frame(Document = pdf_files_caixa,
                          text = sapply(pdf_files_caixa, function(x) 
                            paste0(pdf_text(x), collapse = ' ')))
```

Both of them provide me with the error: "PDF error: Invalid Font Weight"

However when I try to read only one pdf there's no problem, no matter the file.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is an invalid font-weight (as the error message says) at the beginning of at least some PDFs (e. g. in *informemensual-2209-es.pdf*). You should [still be able to read in most of the text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39630212/pdftools-package-in-r-error-invalid-font-weight).

From the {pdftools} documentation:

> Poppler is pretty verbose when encountering minor errors in PDF files,
> in especially pdf_text. These messages are usually safe to ignore, use
> suppressMessages to hide them altogether.

Try, e. g.

```
text_caixa <- 
  list.files(directory_caixa, pattern = "\\.pdf$", full.names = TRUE) |>
  Map(f = \(filename) {
    print(paste('reading', filename))
    pdftools::pdf_text(filename)
  }) |>
  suppressMessages()
```